# ExactTarget/Marketing Cloud SOAP account creation

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

Trying to create an account via the SOAP API & OAuth/client id & client secret. Everything is fine pulling back lists, creating subscribers, etc. Unfortunately when I attempt to create an account I get a `MemberID 722xxxx does not have access to ClientID[732xxxx]` message. Any assistance greatly appreciated. See below SOAP request and response.

---request---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:etns="http://exacttarget.com" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns0="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="true">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>*</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>*</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
      <etns:oAuth>
         <oAuthToken>blanked out for security reasons</oAuthToken>
      </etns:oAuth>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:CreateRequest>
         <ns0:Options>suds.null</ns0:Options>
         <ns0:Objects xsi:type="ns0:AccountUser">
            <ns0:Client>
               <ns0:ID>732xxxx</ns0:ID>
            </ns0:Client>
            <ns0:ID>12345</ns0:ID>
            <ns0:UserID/>
            <ns0:Name>test_account</ns0:Name>
            <ns0:Email/>
            <ns0:Delete>0</ns0:Delete>
         </ns0:Objects>
      </ns0:CreateRequest>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

---response---

```
<Results>
<StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
<StatusMessage>RequestID: 65cecb1c-3792-4b17-9a2a-0a824abee1bd Message: MemberID 722xxxx does not have access to ClientID[732xxxx] PartnerClientKey[] UserID[] PartnerUserKey[] CustomerKey[] supplied in the Client object</StatusMessage>
   <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
   <ErrorCode>2</ErrorCode>
   <NewID>0</NewID>
   <Object xsi:type="AccountUser">
      <Client>
         <ID>732xxxx</ID>
      </Client>
      <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ID>12345</ID>
      <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
      <UserID/>
      <Name>test_account</Name>
      <Email/>
      <Delete>0</Delete>
   </Object>
</Results>
```

Again any help much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Silly question, but does the user have the permissions set to utilize the API functionality.  Should be a checkbox in the edit users section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have every box checked so I should have permission.